# How do I use static void routines made with .NET in VBA?

Tags: .net, vba, dll

I am attempting to send a message via sockets from VBA. I have made static .NET classes to do this (for use in other .NET applications).

How do I use them in VBA?

I found VBA syntax for using shell32.dll functions that look like this, but I can not do this as when I build my library geared for COM use I can't have static routines (and research says COM doesn't like static fields). How did Shell32 do it?

```
Private Declare Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHGetPathFromIDListA" (ByVal pidl As Long, ByVal pszPath As String) As Long
```

I figured out how to do it by having VBA instantiate a class and call the routine from that, but I can only implement this by adding a reference to my .DLL in VBA's References section (which means the end user has to have it installed in a static place).

TL;DR; How do I use static routines made in C# .NET in VBA by having the library in the same directory as the excel file? (.xlsm, or .xlsb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass class objects between VBA and a DLL, only COM objects. You would need to wrap your class in a COM object, with COM methods and properties rather than class methods and properties.

You can also call DLL methods as you provide in the example - those are just functions, not class functions. You would need to (in C#) create a function that then created the class and called the function.